# Speed up MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a sharded collection "my_collection" with the following structure:

```js
{ 
   "CREATED_DATE" : ISODate(...),
   "MESSAGE" : "Test Message",
   "LOG_TYPE": "EVENT"
}
```

The mongoDB environment is sharded with 2 shards. The above collection is sharded using Hashed shard key on LOG_TYPE. There are 7 more other possibilities for LOG_TYPE attribute.

I have 1 million documents in "my_collection" and I am trying to find the count of documents based on the LOG_TYPE using the following query:

```js
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" :{ 
        "_id": "$LOG_TYPE",
        "COUNT": { "$sum":1 }
    }}
])
```

But this is getting me result in about 3 seconds. Is there any way to improve this? Also when I run the explain command, it shows that no Index has been used. Does the group command doesn't use an Index?

Comment: The group operator in the aggregation command willnot use an index, is that representation above acurrate that youonly have three fields in your collection? How large can a message be?

Comment: Since you are in fact aggregating ALL documents in your collection here an index will be useless unless it is an index which produces a covered query, but I am unsure if that will help. MongoDB will still do a scatter and gather operation

Comment: @Sammaye That is not correct. If it is the first and only stage then the index will be selected. See the `explain` output available ( really actually from 2.4.8 ) but from the general premise, the optimizer will sort this out. For much the same reason your answer given actually does no further to optimize the process. Projections are implied in the optimizer if you understand how the code there actually works.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have provided the explain of 2.4.9

Comment: @Sammaye Yes this is the exact representation. MESSAGE attribute will be not more that 150 chars

Comment: I do think this is a network problem, what network is this on?

Comment: This is an Amazon Cloud instance

Comment: Are both shards in the same region and dc? Also where is the client connecting?

Comment: All are in same region. Currently there is no Client. We are just doing some R&D. I tried the same query on one of the primary which has 70% of the data. It took 2.5 seconds. So I don't think its a network issue.

Answer (score 8):

There are currently some limitations in what aggregation framework can do to improve the performance of your query, but you can help it the following way:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort" : { "LOG_TYPE" : 1 } },
    { "$group" :{ 
        "_id": "$LOG_TYPE",
        "COUNT": { "$sum":1 }
    }}
])
```

By adding a sort on LOG_TYPE you will be "forcing" the optimizer to use an index on LOG_TYPE to get the documents in order.  This will improve the performance in several ways, but differently depending on the version being used.

On real data if you have the data coming into the $group stage sorted, it will improve the efficiency of accumulation of the totals.  You can see the different query plans where with $sort it will use the shard key index.  The improvement this gives in actual performance will depend on the number of values in each "bucket" - in general LOG_TYPE having only seven distinct values makes it an extremely poor shard key, but it does mean that it all likelihood the following code will be a lot faster than even optimized aggregation:

```
db.my_collection.distinct("LOG_TYPE").forEach(function(lt) {
   print(db.my_collection.count({"LOG_TYPE":lt});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a limited number of things that you can do in MongoDB, at the end of the day this might be a physical problem that extends beyond MongoDB itself, maybe latency causing configsrvs to respond untimely or results to be brought back from shards too slowly.

However you might be able to solve some performane problems by using a covered query. Since you are in fact sharding on `LOG_TYPE` you will already have an index on it (required before you can shard on it), not only that but the aggregation framework will auto add `projection` so that won't help.

MongoDB is likely having to communicate to every shard for the results, otherwise called a scatter and gather operation.

`$group` on its own will not use an index.

This is my results on 2.4.9:

```
> db.t.ensureIndex({log_type:1})
> db.t.runCommand("aggregate", {pipeline: [{$group:{_id:'$log_type'}}], explain: true})
{
        "serverPipeline" : [
                {
                        "query" : {

                        },
                        "projection" : {
                                "log_type" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "cursor" : {
                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "n" : 1,
                                "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                                "nscanned" : 1,
                                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
                                "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
                                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                "indexOnly" : false,
                                "nYields" : 0,
                                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                "millis" : 0,
                                "indexBounds" : {

                                },
                                "allPlans" : [
                                        {
                                                "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                                "n" : 1,
                                                "nscannedObjects" : 1,
                                                "nscanned" : 1,
                                                "indexBounds" : {

                                                }
                                        }
                                ],
                                "server" : "ubuntu:27017"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$log_type"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

This is the result from 2.6:

```
> use gthtg
switched to db gthtg
> db.t.insert({log_type:"fdf"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.t.ensureIndex({log_type: 1})
{ "numIndexesBefore" : 2, "note" : "all indexes already exist", "ok" : 1 }
> db.t.runCommand("aggregate", {pipeline: [{$group:{_id:'$log_type'}}], explain: true})
{
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "query" : {

                                },
                                "fields" : {
                                        "log_type" : 1,
                                        "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "plan" : {
                                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                        "allPlans" : [
                                                {
                                                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "scanAndOrder" : false
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$log_type"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: The added project operation degraded the performance. Its now taking about 0.5 seconds more. I think as you said mongoDB has to perform a scatter and gather operation and it wont be able to use index for group operation.

Comment: @cj0809 Projection is actually "automatic" in optimization from the properties you select as output. Additional passes are actually forcing a full pass though you collection or otherwise optimized working set and are therefore not a good idea unless you have already reduced to the working set you want.