# mongodb aggregation longer than distinct

Tags: java, mongodb

Here is how I currently do a distinct with MongoDB aggregation framework:

```
db.big.aggregate([ { "$project" : { "first_name" : "$first_name"}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : { "col1" : "$first_name"}}} , { "$limit" : 50000}])
```

And it takes about 3 seconds on a collection that has a little more than 2M documents.
If I run the following query

```
db.big.distinct('first_name')
```

I get pretty much the same result but in less than 1 second.
The issue I have with distinct is that I can not limit it, so if a collection has 1M distinct values for an attribute everything will be returned.
Is there a way to use distinct as it is more performant but also have a limitation on the number of elements that are returned.
I'm using the MongoDB java driver, so I'd need a solution that works with it.

Comment: db.big.distinct('first_name').limit(x)?

Comment: Do you have an index on "first_name"? If so, the [distinct operation will use it and even be covered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/#index-use). On the other hand, the [aggregation framework doesn't use it for grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

Comment: @profesor79 limit does not exist. distinct returns an array.

Comment: @joao no I dont have an index.

Comment: Please create index on this field and check aggregation frame work response

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no way at the moment to use limit with distinct as shown in this [jira task](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130).

Second, the distinct performance will always beat the aggregation framework equivalent. Bucketing/grouping will always be a heavier operation than just checking for distinct values.

Having that, there is only one way to speed the aggregation framework grouping stage, as [explained originally here by Asya Kamsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428314/speed-up-mongodb-aggregation). That is to have your documents sorted by the grouping key before grouping and having and index on the sorting key ([the $sort in the aggregation framework will use the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes)).

```
db.big.ensureIndex({ first_name: 1 }, {background:false})

db.big.aggregate([
    {"$sort": { "first_name": 1 }},
    {"$project": {
        "first_name" : "$first_name"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : "$first_name"
    }},
    { "$limit" : 50000}
])
```

Comment: why not run the $project before the $sort? `db.big.aggregate([
    {"$project": {
        "first_name" : 1," _id":0
    }},
    {"$sort": { "first_name": 1 }},

    { "$group": {
        "_id" : "$first_name"
    }},
    { "$limit" : 50000}
])`

Answer (score 1):

so we need to use aggregation framework here

```
db.big.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : '$first_name'
            }
        }, {
            $skip : 3
        }, {
            $limit : 5
        }
    ])
```

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to avoid using aggregate. From my tests distinct seems to be faster.