# How to improve the performance of this MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I am trying to take an extract from a huge MongoDB collection.

In particular, the collection contains 2.65TB data (unzipped), i.e., 600GB data (zipped). Each document has a deep hierarchy and a couple of arrays and I want to extract some parts out of them. In this collection we have multiple documents for each customer id. Since I want to export the most active document for each customer, I need to group and take the records with the maximum timestamp field and perform some further processing on them. I need some help in forming the query for the export. I have tried to sort the documents per customer id, but this could not be achieved in an acceptable time when combined with a 'match' construct (this is needed since it is a huge collection and we try to create the export in parts). Currently the query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('CEM').aggregate([
    {'$match' : {'LiveFeed.customer.profile.id':'TCAYT2RY2PF93R93JVSUGU7D3'}},
    {'$project':{'LiveFeed.customer.profile.id':1,'LiveFeed.customer.profile.products.air.flights':1, 'LiveFeed.context.timestamp':1}},
    {'$sort':{'LiveFeed.customer.profile.id':1,"LiveFeed.context.timestamp":1}},
    {'$group':{'_id':'$LiveFeed.customer.profile.id',
      'products':{'$last':'$LiveFeed.customer.profile.products.air.flights'}}},
    {'$unwind': '$products'},
    {'$unwind': '$products.sources'},
    {'$project':{'_id':0,
        'ceid': '$_id',
        'coupon_no':{'$ifNull':['$products.couponId.couponNumber', ""]},
        'ticket_no':{'$ifNull':['$products.couponId.ticketId.number','']},
        'pnr_id':'$products.sources.id',
        'departure_date':'$products.segment.departure.at',
        'departure_airport':'$products.segment.departure.code',
        'arrival_airport':'$products.segment.arrival.code',
        'created_date':'$products.createdAt'}}])
```

Any ideas/suggestions on to how to improve this query will be very helpful indeed - Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you are looking for tuning the query performance. Here I have an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595803/mongodb-aggregate-pipeline-slow-after-first-match-step/57713897#57713897

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this without knowing the indexes on your collection. However, you can save some time by eliminating stage 3. The $sort is undone by the $group in stage 4. See [$group does not preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599311/8540240)